# How to include unique grouping variables in plot titles and file names when using plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, iteration, plotly, paste

I am learning to use `plotly`. I have a data set similar to `data` created below. The .html plots created using the code below work as I want them to; a unique "interactive" plot is created for each unique `ID`. However, I am having trouble incorporating my grouping variable `Group`. I would like for the name of the grouping variable to be included in the title of each plot, and the name of each file. For instance, the title of the plot created below will say `"plot_for_ID_A"`. I want it to say `"plot_for_Alpha_A"`, with `Alpha` referring to the grouping variable. I have tried multiple things in the paste function, I have tried putting `filter(group==.y)` under the `filter()` call so that I can refer to `.y` in the `paste()` call, and several other things that didn't work. What is the best way to do this?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ID <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), each=1000)
Group <- rep(c("alpha","beta"), each = 3000)
time <- rep(c(1:1000), times = 6)
one <- rnorm(6000)
two <- rnorm(6000)  
three <- rnorm(6000)
four <- rnorm(6000)
five<-rnorm(6000)
data <- data.frame(cbind(ID,Group,time,one,two,three,four,five),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data_long <- data %>%
pivot_longer(-c(ID:time), names_to="Variable", values_to="Value")%>% 
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time),
         value = as.numeric(Value))


walk(unique(data_long$ID),
    ~ htmlwidgets::saveWidget(ggplotly(data_long %>% 
                                filter(ID == .x) %>% 
                                ggplot(aes(x = time, 
                                           y = value, 
                                           color = Variable)) +
                                geom_point() +
                                labs(title = paste(.x))),
                              paste("plot_for_ID_", .x, ".html", sep = "")))
```

Also, the output of this code creates a unique .html file for each plot. Is there a way to paste all the plots into a single file where each plot has its own page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group_split` to split data based on groups and get the name of the plot from it's columns values.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

data_long %>%
  group_split(ID, Group) %>%
  map(~ htmlwidgets::saveWidget(ggplotly(
                                  ggplot(.x, aes(x = time, 
                                                 y = value, 
                                              color = Variable)) +
                                   geom_point() +
               labs(title = paste0("plot_for_", .x[[2]][1], "_", .x[[1]][1]))),
               paste0("plot_for_", .x[[2]][1], "_", .x[[1]][1], ".html")))
```